# Stopping svn-autoreleasedeb

Tags: debian, svn

**How can you stop the program?**

My auth.log has regularly similar entries as follows

```
Jan  2 03:15:01 lumi CRON[28939]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user svn-autoreleasedeb by (uid=0)
Jan  2 03:15:01 lumi CRON[28939]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user svn-autoreleasedeb
Jan  2 03:17:01 lumi CRON[28949]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan  2 03:17:01 lumi CRON[28949]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 03:20:01 lumi CRON[28955]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user svn-autoreleasedeb by (uid=0)
Jan  2 03:20:01 lumi CRON[28955]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user svn-autoreleasedeb
Jan  2 03:25:01 lumi CRON[29370]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user svn-autoreleasedeb by (uid=0)
Jan  2 03:25:01 lumi CRON[29370]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user svn-autoreleasedeb
Jan  2 03:30:01 lumi CRON[29467]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user svn-autoreleasedeb by (uid=0)
Jan  2 03:30:01 lumi CRON[29467]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user svn-autoreleasedeb
Jan  2 03:35:01 lumi CRON[29499]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user svn-autoreleasedeb by (uid=0)
Jan  2 03:35:01 lumi CRON[29499]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user svn-autoreleasedeb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that a cronjob was run for the user `svn-autoreleasedeb`. You can search for cronjobs for a specific user in

- `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.d`
- and with the command `crontab -u svn-autoreleasedeb -e`

If you really want to disable the cronjob then, just comment the lines with a `#` in front.

Additional information can be found in the manpages of cron and crontab(5)

Answer (score 1):

Your cron file shoud be ["/etc/cron.d/svn-autoreleasedeb"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/all/svn-autoreleasedeb/filelist).

Maybe you can remove the package [svn-autoreleasedeb](http://packages.debian.org/sid/svn-autoreleasedeb).